# Apache subdomain can not be resolved

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, dns, dynamic-dns

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName domain.no-ip.org
    ServerAlias www.domain.no-ip.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/main

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

These are my settings in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`.
I have a webserver at home connected via "no-ip" (dynamic dns).

When I try to go on "www.domain.no-ip.org" I get redirected to the site "http://navigationshilfe1.t-online.de/http://navigationshilfe1.t-online.de/dnserror?url=http://www.domain.no-ip.org/" of my ISP.

The basename is `dnserror`. Nice little, very little, information.

I don't know the mechanics of DNS. Can somebody tell me where the problem is?

---

Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

Comment: Well, it has nothing to do with the Apache configuration at least, because the web server is never reached. For some reason, “www.domain.no-ip.org” does not resolve. Are you sure there aren’t any typos anywhere? Have you waited for a reasonable time (say, a couple of hours) after setting up the dynamic DNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need no-ip.org to support your “www.” subdomain.  You'll need to get the [enhanced feature](http://www.noip.com/services/managed_dns/enhanced_dynamic_dns.html) from no-ip.org for it to ever work.

Or alternatively (might be even cheaper), buy your own domain name and make the domain and all the subdomains you want point to your single no-ip.org address.

Comment: OP could also do what I do: Pay $10 for the domain and use zonomi.com for free. They give you the base domain plus two or three host records for free. Once they're on zonomi, they just make a host record for "www", do the wget magic like on the main domain, and call it good.

Comment: @JoelDavis - good tip, never heard of zonomi.com before.